# Google suggest queries with Scriptaculous Autocompleter?

Tags: autocomplete, scriptaculous, autosuggest

I'm trying to display Google suggested queries when a user types in a query into our search text field.  Our goal is to combine Google suggested queries with the Scriptaculous Autocompleter.

Here's our code:

new Ajax.Autocompleter('q', 'autocomplete_choices', 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?q=test', {method:'get', onSuccess:format_autocomplete});

Fetching **http: //suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?q=test** from a browser and from curl works fine and displays the queries suggested for a given string.

However, the **responseText** in my **onSuccess** callback always shows the empty string ("") instead of the suggested queries.

Any clues?

Comment: FYI, I viewed the AJAX response from Firebug, and here's what it says:

Failed to load source for: http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?q=test

Comment: I also tried http://google.com/complete/search?q=test, and that also failed with a 400 Bad Request even though the same URL works fine in a browser and curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: http://jimbojw.com/wiki/index.php?title=What_Would_Google_Suggest%3F

Briefly, the problem stems from security restrictions on cross-domain AJAX requests.  The workaround is on-demand Javascript or Javascript on-demand (JoD).

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think that JSONP is the answer!
jQuery UI autocomplete widget has this feature by deafault